# Android Studio: What does this Error mean?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am making an App with Android Studio, but when starting the App i have got this Error:

> Error:(45, 61) error: as of release 8, 'this' is allowed as the
>   parameter name for the receiver type only, which has to be the first
>   Parameter

There are some red lines in only this Code

```
Sender s = new Sender(getActivity().this, urlAddress, parameter1,parameter2,parameter3,parameter4,parameter5);
            s.execute();
```

This is in a Tab Fragment with this Code:

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.text, container, false);
    return view;
}
```

Comment: `getActivity().this` how did you produce this?

Comment: use (this)  instead of  getActivity().this

Comment: if you need context use getContext()

Comment: `ew Sender(getActivity()` remove this

Comment: Context is excpected, but getContext.this does not work and only getContext does not work either :(

Comment: You should look up what `this` keyword means in Java and how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` in Java refers to the current object... which in your case is the fragment you're calling the code from.

`getActivity()` on the other hand refer to the activity to which the fragment is attached.

so `getActivity().this` doesn't actually mean anything. If you're trying to get a context you just have to use `getActivity()` without the `.this` since an activity extends a context

if you're executing your code inside a fragment use

```
Sender s = new Sender(getActivity(), 
                      urlAddress, 
                      parameter1,
                      parameter2,
                      parameter3,
                      parameter4,
                      parameter5);
s.execute();
```

if it's inside an activity use

```
Sender s = new Sender(this, 
                      urlAddress, 
                      parameter1,
                      parameter2,
                      parameter3,
                      parameter4,
                      parameter5);
s.execute();
```